# How to find a specific time milliseconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js.My code is like

```
var nextDate = moment().add(30,'days');
```

This returns 30 day later date time.Now I want to convert this time in miliseconds.
but I couldn't.How can I convert to date into miliseconds?
Thanks

Comment: the result is it javascript date obect or string? Can you post the result..

Comment: result like  Fri Apr 10 2015 09:39:25 GMT+0300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get timestamp in milliseconds

```
var todaydate = new Date();
var millisecondTimestamp = Date.parse(todaydate);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpwLyvem/)

Comment: I tried.Stackoverflow said you can not accept an answer in 6 minutes. after 6 minutes I will accept :)

Comment: Wow that was a really fast answer :P

Comment: You can just do `+todaydate` to get the millisecond FYI, and you shouldn't be using `Date.parse` since it is [supposed to receive a String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse), not a `Date` object. Internally it will have to cast the `Date` object to a string, and then casting it back to an integer, where doing `+todaydate`/`todaydate.getTime()` can directly cast it to an integer.

Comment: @Derek 朕會功夫: Doing +todaydate/todaydate.getTime() gives slightly different result. http://jsfiddle.net/tpwLyvem/2/ and correct result come from Date.parse(todaydate). Check here http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/#.VP_8gPmUd1Y. Why is it doing that?

Comment: @planet260 In your fiddle `Date.parse` is returning an incorrect value because when it casts the object to a String, the millisecond portion of the date is lost. On the other hand, the `+` operator correctly returns the time in millisecond of the date object is because the Date object itself internally overrode `toNumber`. `getTime` behaves the same as casting it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If nextDate is of type Date you can get the timestamp (in milliseconds) like that :

```
var timestamp = nextDate.getTime()
```